# How to change unwanted character insertion from TeXworks?

Tags: texworks

Whenever I hit " on my keyboard, the TeXworks editor inserts `` instead.
How/where can this annoyance be changed?

Comment: `Format` - `Smart Quotes` - `None`.  I agree that one is a real pain to find, because it is not in the primary location: `Edit` - `Preferences`.  I also prefer `Format` - `Auto-indent mode` - `None`, as well.

Comment: This solved it! Thx.